# Metamask is not connecting to Goerli test net

Tags: metamask, wallets, web3-providers, goerli

For some reason I cannot connect to the Goerli network:

[image]

after spinning is completed, I get message "cannot connect. switch to a different network". I switched to "mainnet", wallet connects to the mainnet, `window.ethereum` is injected but this time this line of code returns false

```
 isInstalled: ethereum?.isMetaMask || false,
```

Even though `window.ethereum` is injected

[image]

Answer (score 1):

probably metamask's goreli RPC url is broken, try to replace them. Or create new goreli network connection with correct chainID and RPC url.